# How to stop just the first processor

Tags: apache-nifi

Is there any way to stop just the first processor of a NiFi process group?

I know that through the Nifi API it is possible to stop the whole group of processors but what I want is to stop only the first processor of that group since I know the id of that group.

Comment: possible to get all processors of the group, find processors without incoming queues and stop them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `/nifi-api/flow/process-groups/{processGroupId}`(GET) api to filter `processors` array and find a processor with the `inputPorts` array empty and the `outputPorts` array with a size that is greater than zero. 
Then, just take its id and stop it.